# Priority of overloaded operators in Ruby

Tags: ruby, operators, operator-overloading

I have a class that overloads the operators '&' , '|' and '!'.I was wondering about their priority level.I mean, if I had this:

```
instance1 & instance2 | isntance3
```

is it guaranteed that the first thing that is going to happen will be `instance1 & instance2`

and then on the result-> `result | isntance3`

Comment: Regardless of the answer, it's probably a good idea to use parentheses in cases like these.

Comment: You can easily answer this yourself with irb: i1 = [1,2,3]; i2 = [1,4]; i3 = [5]; i1 & i2 | i3 # => [1, 5]; (i1 & i2) | i3 # => [1, 5]; i1 & (i2 | i3) => [1]